# Why is "YYYY-MM-DD HH':'MM':'SS" DateTime Format Displaying Incorrectly?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, datetime-format

```
 DateTime timeUtcWhenCommentPostingOccurred = getDateAndTimeOfCommentPostingInUtc();
 DateTime estTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtcWhenCommentPostingOccurred, estZone);


 estTime.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD HH':'MM':'SS");
```

The above specified format shows the following Incorrect date format :

YYYY-11-DD 21:11:SS

Why does the year, day and second fail to show up properly?  Please provide suggestions as to how I can fix the issue above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Because its lower case `y` for Year, not upper case `Y`.
- Same is the case with Day, its lower case `d` not upper case `D`
- With Minutes its lower case `m` not upper case `M`, upper case `M` is
  for month,
- For seconds it lower case `s`, not upper case `S`
- Also remove the single quote in your format, since you don't want to escape string literals

See:[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So your format should be:

```
estTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 3):

[Format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are care-sensitive.  `YYYY`, `DD`, and `SS` are not recognized format strings for `DateTime`, so they are treated as literal characters.

Use

```
estTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

instead.

Note the distinction between `MM` (month) and `mm` (minute).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
estTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

C# is case sensitive and format strings are case sensitive too

Also check this useful [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You got the case wrong:

```
estTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is case sensitive and the case has a meaning in datetime format strings.

`yyyy` is the year, `MM` the month, `dd` the day and `mm` the minute. Uppercase `HH` means 24h hour clock. This gives the expected output:

```
string output = estTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: So hh lowercase means 12h hour clock? I'm having issues with that on an Android/Windows cross platform app

Answer (score 1):

For full reference check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszyst2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN article. Try:

```
estTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss");
```