# DateTime.ParseExact() - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss YYYY

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I have a string:

```
Fri Feb 14 00:15:38 2020"
```

I try to parse this string using `ParseExact()`:

```
var time = DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss YYYY", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

I have tried several cultures. Nothing works.

> String 'Fri Feb 14 00:15:38 2020' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Well... that's not a valid format, is it? `YYYY` should be `yyyy` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#year-y-format-specifier

Comment: This question should be closed either as "caused by a typo" or as duplicate of [Why is "YYYY-MM-DD HH':'MM':'SS" DateTime Format Displaying Incorrectly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20197352/8967612)

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is use the format string to also **output** your desired date:

```
var formatString = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss YYYY";
var d = new DateTime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 15, 38);
Console.WriteLine(d);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(formatString));
```

[Run that](http://%20https://dotnetfiddle.net/B98YZb), and you get this:

```
Fri Feb 14 00:15:38 YYYY
```

And now we can clearly see that, oops, looks like the year is wrong. Fix it to use lower-case `Y`s as so:

```
    var formatString = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy";
    var d = new DateTime(2020, 2, 14, 0, 15, 38);
    Console.WriteLine(d);
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(formatString));
```

and [now we see the correct value](http://%20https://dotnetfiddle.net/T1ncl5):

```
Fri Feb 14 00:15:38 2020
```

Which happens to match [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

We can now also used the corrected format string for the parse operation:

```
var time = DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: Or, a shorter answer: "read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#year-y-format-specifier"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I was getting to that.